# how can i add red wavy underline in textarea field for detected errors in spell checker

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I am working on a spellchecker for Flask framework. I used JavaScript to send the tokens of words to the backend and successfully detect the errors(misspelt words). but, I cannot apply wavy red underline for misspelt words when written in real-time.
here is a sample of my code:
`function tokenizeText() {
var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText").value;

```
fetch("/tokenize", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        text: inputText,
    }),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
 
    console.log("Returned Tokens:", data.tokens);

   
    fetch("/detect_errors", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            tokens: data.tokens,
        }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       
        console.log("Detected Errors:", data.errors);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
})
.catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
```

}
`

I tried to add the red wavy underline by replacing the textarea in my template code for the input field by content div, but, it doesn't work for me.
When I press space or enter, I want to make wavy red underline the misspelt word in real-time when they typed on the input field by using the detected errors from the backend

Comment: Instead of textarea, use a contenteditable div. This allows you to manipulate the content and apply styling to specific words or phrases. After receiving the detected errors from the backend, apply styling to the misspelled words in the contenteditable div. You can use the span element with a specific class for this purpose. Add an event listener to the contenteditable div to trigger the spellcheck function when space or enter is pressed.

Comment: @ManojAgrawal. I tried it by contenteditable div. but, it causes another problem that is moving the cursors to the start. for example when I try to write the word nama, it written as aman